# Store the state of App before it crashes

Tags: android

I am working on an app that extensively requires server connection and also location updates from GPS.
And the app is to be used on road. I have tried to minimize the chances of crashing of app due to internet connection or due to unexpected data from server but still there are chances of crashing. Now what I want to do is to restore the application when it starts again, to previous state therefore I need to store its state before crashing.

Now, what is the better way to do that?

I have tried onDestroy but it isn't called everytime the app crashes.

How can I do That?

Thaks In Advance.

Comment: There's no callback for crash. You can try follow @Nabin advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completely depends on how your app works, what kind of information you want to store.

You can save values to **shared preference** repeatedly(like checkpointing) and when app crashes and the app restarts you can fetch the values from preference

Comment: I have tried it earlier, but I wanted to know if there is any other way better then that. But thanks, any how, for ur reply.

Answer (score 2):

[Google says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> [..] you should use the `onPause()` method to write any persistent
>   data (such as user edits) to storage.

If you have to persist data, do it in `onPause()`, because this lifecycle callback is guaranteed to be invoked, if the process of your Application or the Activity will be killed by the OS.

Comment: It means whether the app crashes on killed by OS or like force stopped from app settings, onPause will b definitely called ?

Answer (score -1):

Of course the best way it's make application without crashes, and if app has connection problems just tell that to user. But if you know where crashes happens you can do something like that:

```
    try
    {
     // some logic with internet connection
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     // here you can save your current progress or some data to database or to shared     preferences
    }
```

Comment: How is this the best idea? Using try catch is never the best idea.

Comment: I know that try-catch is not the best way. The best way is fix app, that it should work without crashes. BUT as Massab said "there is some chance for crash" , so I mean when crash happened, we must handle it somehow and in addition we can save some information.

Comment: @user1652236 I already have done Exception Handling but still there can b chances like "bad data" in case, can crash the application.